# SSH - how to specify path for user certificate?

Tags: ssh

I've followed [this guide](https://goteleport.com/blog/how-to-configure-ssh-certificate-based-authentication/) to configure SSH certificates. The guide guides you to create the files: `user-key`, `user-key.pub` and `user-key-cert.pub`. Then, when connection to the server, you should run:

```
$ ssh -i user-key <user>@<host>
```

So I guess that SSH automatically loads the file with the same name and ends with `-cert.pub` as the certificate.

In case I want to keep it in some other path, is there a way to specify the certificate path somehow?

Comment: Did the answers solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

For client you do not need public key as it can be generated from private one. You need public to copy it to target machine to make ssh key login session.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CertificateFile` option (via `-o` or `~/.ssh/config`):

```
ssh -i foo.priv -o CertificateFile=foo.cert targethost
```